# How can I eliminate /public in a Laravel 9 Inertia.js project on Digital Ocean?

Tags: vuejs3, digital-ocean, laravel-9, inertiajs

I'm working on a Laravel 9 project that uses Inertia.js, and I'm encountering an issue related to the directory structure on the server. In the development environment, Laravel 9 serves static files from the `/public` folder, but on the Digital Ocean server, I would like to eliminate the need to use `/public` in the URL.

How can I configure my Laravel 9 project so that static files are served directly from the root directory of my domain, rather than having to access them through `/public`?

I have already set up a Digital Ocean server and successfully deployed my project, but I'm struggling to adjust this specific configuration. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.